# Can't get rid of white margin on div's

Tags: javascript, html, css, margins, removing-whitespace

So, I have tried everything I can think of to get rid of the white margins around everything on my page.

I have put: `margin: 0;`  on everything I can think of and it still does not get rid of it. Any help would be great!

I apologize for the giant wall of code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/* global */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #454545;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
}


/* end global */


/* custom */

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.footer {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #428cd9;
}


/* end custom */


/* custom responsive */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}


/*end custom responsive */


/* navbar */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #428cd9;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #454545;
  padding: 0px 16px;
  line-height: 3.0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #2162a6;
  color: #757575;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}


/* end navbar */


/* responsive navbar */

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(: first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* end responsive navbar */

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  .nomobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .yesmobile {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.header-img {
  min-height: 300px;
  background-image: url(http://thirdshiftdesigns.net/images/cabheader2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center top;
  /*padding: 40px; (If don't want to set min-height or some image content is there) */
}

.end-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #428cd9;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="col-12">

    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="header-img">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="end-header">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end header -->
  <!-- footer -->
  <div class="col-12">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Margins around everything" is quite vague. Are you sure you're looking at margins and not some padding you applied on other elements?

Comment: reset padding on the specific div you want 
  `div.col-12 {
  padding:0
}` https://jsfiddle.net/kfexozkh/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the element, you can find that the unwanted space is because of the following style which applies `padding` to all elements with the `class` value containing `col-`.

```
[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Override the style and you can get rid of the unwanted space. Note that this will set the `padding` to 0 for all the classes whose value contains `col-`.

```
[class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Or you can only override the `padding` of `.col-12` which will apply padding of 0 to `.col-12` while the other classes containing `col-` will still get a padding of 15px.

```
.col-12 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: that was it! the little "col-" bit

Answer (score 1):

You're wrapping many elements in a `.col-12` class. All `.col-` elements are set in your CSS to contain `15px` of `padding` around the edges. Here's a screenshot from inspecting the page in Chrome Developer Tools where you can see the element highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set padding to 0 on the col-12 element.

change the following in your CSS

```
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

to

```
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfexozkh/4/)

Comment: this was indeed it! can't believe i missed that. -_-

Comment: One trick I use all the time for stuff like this is right click (using Chrome browser) on the problem area / white space and choose INSPECT... it will show the Chrome Dev Tools that show the properties for the element and you can troubleshoot the specific issue.